# python deployment pacakge issue

Tags: aws-lambda

I am using module paramiko in my python code which is an aws lambda function.
I followed same procedure in python package deployment following the link  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python

I got some strange error after running the deployment package

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you're following AWS documentation, but I'm not sure exactly how you are creating the deployment package, so I'll try to illustrate with an example.

My Python code(3.5)

```
/paramiko
   /paramiko
       my_function.py
 requirements.txt
```

Where `requirements.txt`:

```
paramiko==2.3.1
```

`my_function.py` contains:

```
import paramiko
print(paramiko.__version__)
```

Creating the virtual environment.

1. Create the virtualenv: `python3 -m venv /path/to/your/venv`.
2. Navigate to the venv root, and activate it: `source bin/activate`.
3. Install dependencies: `pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. Execute the following shell commands from the root of your venv:

   - `cd lib/python3.5/site-packages/`
   - `zip -r9 ~/my_deployment_package.zip *`
   - `cd /path/to/your/project/root`
   - `zip -g ~/my_deployment_package.zip *`

You should have a deployment package, `~/my_deployment_package` that contains all the dependencies for your project.

Comment: I got error after following the same:                                                  START RequestId: 1f274fa1-b73c-11e7-affa-abb6aac08c79 Version: $LATEST
No module named '_cffi_backend': ModuleNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/cw.py", line 8, in lambda_handler
    import paramiko
  File "/var/task/paramiko/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/var/task/paramiko/transport.py", line 57, in <module>
    from paramiko.ed25519key import Ed25519Key